# Cannot set href and src of an element in js

Tags: javascript, html, dom, href, src

I have this javascript code in Tampermonkey:

```
var footerDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("copyright")[0];

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var button = document.createElement('button')
    footerDiv.append(button)
    button.src = 'https://img.shields.io/badge/%20-ComuBot--Tranlator-%23159818';
    button.href = "https://github.com/AnonHexo/public-scripts";
    button.id = 'srcButton';
})
```

but when i run the code the button doesn't appear (appears as a dot ".") and it doesn't have src and href properties.

the site where i'm trying to add a button is https://comubot.cf

please help me. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A button element doesn't have `src` and `href` attributes. Instead of that, you can use an image and anchor element to fulfill your task

```js
var footerDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("copyright")[0];

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.id='srcButton';
    a.href = "https://github.com/AnonHexo/public-scripts";
    
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = 'https://img.shields.io/badge/%20-ComuBot--Tranlator-%23159818';
    a.append(img)
    footerDiv.append(a)
})
```

```html
<div class="copyright"></div>
```